# Makefile with pthread library?

Tags: makefile, pthreads, semaphore

I'm doing a project for University about UDP communication; i need compile with -pthread because i need a semaphore; i tried copy what i found on this forum, but it doesn't run..This is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O2
SRC = create_children4.o clientUDP3.o socket_operation.o

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJ)
    ${CC} create_children4.o socket_operation.o -o create_children4
    ${CC} clientUDP3.o socket_operation.o -o clientUDP3




create_children4.o: socket_operation.h
clientUDP3.o: socket_operation.h
socket_operation.o: 


clean:
    rm -f *.o core 

cleanall:
    rm -f *.o core create_children4 clientUDP3
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `-pthread` to the end of your CFLAGS array?

Comment: no, i have tried :/

Comment: Try adding it, then adding `${CFLAGS}` after the `${CC}` lines in your `all:` target.

Comment: i have to write  ${CFLAGS}  only one time after ${CC}?Or have i to add it after every line?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Makefiles- that's why I'm writing comments, not answers. But from [http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/](this tutorial) , it looks like you don't need to write it after every line. Instead, maybe replace `${CC}` with `$(CC)`?

Comment: But I don't want to give you bad advice, so I'm bowing out. Good luck; sorry if I mislead you

Comment: There's nothing we can do to help because _it doesn't run_ is in no way a sufficient description of the problem.  What doesn't run?  Does the make command fail?  If so what errors do you see?  Or does the make work but your program doesn't run?  Please describe precisely what the problem is and cut and paste error messages you see.

Comment: make fails because it doesn't find reference to semaphore functions, because i have to add -pthread; but i don't know where